# How to ignore NAN turning to String when using df.applymap(str)

Tags: python, pandas

I have to turn all the items in dataframe into string and i have tried as below,

```
df = df.applymap(str)
```

but it turns nan to string. How can i avoid nan to string here?

i tried as below, but not working.

```
df.where(~df.notna(),df.applymap(str))
```

**Edit**
i tried df.applymap(str) but some reason i am getting boolean value of NA is ambiguous with my dataframe so i am opting only df.applymap(str)

Comment: Does this help? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html
Seems you can add the argument `na_action='ignore'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try  :

```py
df = df.fillna('').astype(str)
```

Or you can have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53901398/convert-column-to-string-retaining-nan-as-none-or-blank).

Comment: i tried df.applymap(str) but some reason i am getting "boolean value of NA is ambiguous" with my dataframe so i am opting only df.applymap(str)

Comment: What about adding a `fillna('')` before the `astype(str)` ?